# Indirect or tonic pronoun for preposition "à"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

Sometimes the preposition *à* is used with an indirect pronoun:

> Je vais **lui** téléphoner.
>
> Je **leur** ai demandé de m'aider.

Sometimes it is used with a tonic pronoun:

> Je pense à **elle**.
>
> Je crois qu'il s'intéresse à **moi**.

When I look up a dictionary, I can't distinguish between these two cases, because the entries are *téléphoner à qn*, *penser à qn*, etc.

Is there a way to tell if a certain verb should belong to one of the cases? For example, if I see the entry *s'appliquer à qn*, how can I know whether I should say

> Cette règle ne s'applique pas à **nous**.

or

> Cette règle ne **nous** s'applique pas.

I think it should be the first one, but I don't know a good rule to use to tell which one it should be.

Comment: The rule is: there is no rule. An interesting topic with many attempts to find a rule, systematically followed by counterexamples: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-lui-parle-je-pense-%C3%A0-lui-pronom-indirect-conjoint-disjoint.812023/?hl=fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an interesting attempt to give a rule on this topic: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-lui-parle-je-pense-%C3%A0-lui-pronom-indirect-conjoint-disjoint.812023/?hl=fr

Of course there are counterexamples. And counter-counterexamples. And other rules mixing with this one.

The explanation is:

- When you can say **verb** + **something** + **to someone**, you use the indirect pronoun
- When you can only say **verb** + **to someone**, you use the tonic pronoun (but not if it's **verb** + **to something**)

> Parler de quelque chose à quelqu'un = Je lui parle de mon voyage
>   Faire attention à quelqu'un = Je fais attention à lui
>   Faire attention à quelque chose = J'y fais attention

*Téléphoner à* is one of the exceptions.

Now I don't know if there are too many exceptions to make this a rule.

Comment: Thanks. For *s'appliquer à qn*, it is *Cette règle ne s'applique pas à nous*, right?

Comment: @user11550 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Simon's comment : there is no rule, this is part of vocabulary learning, like for French people learning English, we need to learn weather a verb is transitive or not.

In french, verbs can be intransitive or transitive. But transitive verbs can be separated again between "transitifs directs" et "transitifs indirects". The first ones are followed by a "complément d'objet direct", so without the "à" préposition, and indirect transitives ones are followed by a "complément d'objet indirect", and require a préposition ("à" or "de").

Yeah... French is quite tricky ^^ As I heard recently, we can say that in French, every time there is a rule, there is an exception to this rule and an exception to this exception !

Here is a link for further information and exercices : http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-verbes-transitifs-et-intransitifs-152.php

Comment: Hum, this is not the question. The question is about **intransitive verbs with the preposition *à*** and why sometimes we use the indirect pronoun (me, te, lui, nous, vous, leur) and sometimes the preposition *à* with the tonic pronoun (à moi, à toi, à lui, à elle, à nous, à vous, à eux, à elles). *Penser à quelqu'un* = *je pense à toi*, *parler à quelqu'un* = *je te parle*.

Comment: Hum exact, I see... even more tricky I guess. As expressed by user11550, there is this "feeling" of what sounds right...

Comment: Woops sorry, new to StackExchange, <Enter> sent the comment... 
I wanted to add that, again, I think it's part of vocabualry learning, like for English verbs say (to someone) and tell (someone) if I'm not mistaken... (or again with "hear something" and "listen to something") 

I may ignore it if it exists, but I don't think there is a rule in English for these examples others than knowing the expressions ?